# Is it possible to check if a cache line is invalid and/or a way to manually revalidate a cache line?

Tags: caching, x86, multicore

(I'm primarily interested in x86 architectures, but would be interested to hear if there's a way to do this in other architectures also)

Is there any way to programmatically check the state of a cache line containing a certain memory address?  I don't want to read the contents of that address, and don't want the penalty of reading from main memory incurred from a cache miss, I just want to check the state of the cache line.

And is there any way to programmatically revalidate an invalid cache line without writing through to memory? (well, I guess with MESI, by "revalidate" I mean change its state to "Modified")

Comment: What is the motivation for this ? Normally this kind of thing is completely transparent to user programs.

Comment: I'm experimenting with locking algorithms in speed critical situations.

Comment: Some embedded PowerPC CPUs give you control over various aspects of the cache, but I'm not aware of anything like this on general purpose CPUs such as x86.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to use the PREFETCH optimization hint. So, instead of:

```
mov eax, (DWORD PTR [esi])
```

You would do:

```
prefetch [esi]
;
; give processor time to load cacheline...
;
mov eax, (DWORD PTR [esi])
```

Fundamentally I think what you're trying to do is flawed. If you were running on a custom single-tasking operating system it might work, but on today's modern multi-tasking systems it's simply impossible to control the processor like that.

Answer (score 0):

Cache is completely invisible to programmer. Programmer works with virtual addresses while cache work with physical addresses.